# delay jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have this function inside onther my function

```
setInterval(function () {       

    self.find('li').removeClass('main-item');
    self.find('li:nth-child(3)').addClass('main-item')
        .delay(10000)
        .queue(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('main-item');
        $(this).dequeue();
    });

    self.find('li:nth-child(1)')
        .delay(8000)
        .animate({opacity: 0}, {
        duration: 800,
        queue: false,
        complete: function () {
            setTimeout( function(){
              $(this).css({opacity: 1});
                },1200);
            }
    });

    self.find('li:nth-child(4)').css({opacity: 0}); 

    self.find('li:nth-child(4)')
        .delay(30000)
        .animate({opacity: 1}, {
        duration: 2000,
        queue: false
    });

}, 10000);
```

and as I see in this part delay doesn't work

```
self.find('li:nth-child(4)')
        .delay(30000)
        .animate({opacity: 1}, {
        duration: 2000,
        queue: false
    });
```

I can put any number in delay, but it stayes the same.
What's wrong? How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The `queue` property, if `false`, will make the animation start immediately. Try not adding it at all, simply make your code to be:

```
self.find('li:nth-child(4)')     // fourth child, which is an `li`
    .delay(30000)                // after 30 seconds
    .animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);// make opacity 1 in 2 seconds
```

[Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)